# How to set number of articles per page on the Blog module?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I came across a 6.15 drupal site that I had to modify one simple thing:
put instead of 3 articles per page , 5 
on the front page the blog resume is shown, and it seem that the blog module doesn't have any setting to do that..
It isn't made with views, nor is it a block.. I don't even know how they get to the front page (probably by being promoted..)

here a snapshot of what I see on the front page...
[image]

how can I set the number of articles?
I can't find it anywhere...
I was thinking of defining a view or something and renounce of this built-in functionality...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [blog_page_last](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--blog--blog.pages.inc/function/blog_page_last/6) and [node_page_default](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_page_default/6), I see that both use the persistent variable called "default_nodes_main" (which defaults to 10) for the number of nodes per page. That variable can be set on the form at /admin/content/node-settings, under "Number of posts on main page".

The above means that both the /node and /blog pages use the same value. If you want different values for both pages, you probably need to rebuild one (or both) of them as a view.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: Yes it does, indeed is the built-in functionality from drupal that shows promoted pages . thanks so much

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 7, there is a setting on admin/config/system/site-information to control post numbers on pages like blog called *Number of posts on front page*.

As its description says, the setting is:

> The maximum number of posts displayed on overview pages such as the front page.

There is a similar setting for the Views module, which is for each view you create with this module.

Comment: I'm new in drupal and I've set Number of posts on front page to 5 but my pagination link doesn't showing. When I put URL like `my-url?page=1` then it shows remaining entries. Then what is the problem. Please help

Answer (score -1):

in blog.pages.inc,under blog_page_last() function,replace

```
->limit(variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10)) to ->limit('YOUR CUSTOM VALUE').
```

i think it will help you.

Comment: it's hacking a core, so this is not the best way to resolve it